# Retrieving multiple values from table using multiple WHERE conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, select, jdbc

I have this table in MYSQL database (see image attached)

[image: database]

I would like to retrieve the column "cable" for three different apartments.  This is what I have in my code so far, but it is not working, any idea why?

```
try
{
        //Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        //Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:db1","","");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/etoolsco_VecinetSM?user=etoolsco&password=g7Xm2heD41");
        Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
        String query;
        query="SELECT cable FROM flatene2013 WHERE Apto='5C' JOIN SELECT cable FROM flatene2013 WHERE Apto='5Cest1' JOIN SELECT cable FROM flatene2013 WHERE Apto='5Cest2'";            
        ResultSet resultSet=statement.executeQuery(query);
        while(resultSet.next())
    {%>
    <tr>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right"><font size="-1"><%out.println(resultSet.getBigDecimal(1)+"");%></font></td>
    <td align="right"><font size="-1"><%out.println(resultSet.getBigDecimal(2)+"");%></font></td>
    <td align="right"><font size="-1"><%out.println(resultSet.getBigDecimal(3)+"");%></font></td>
    </tr>
    <%
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

use `UNION` instead of `JOIN`

```
SELECT  cable , Apto
FROM    flatene2013 
WHERE   Apto='5C' 
UNION
SELECT  cable , Apto 
FROM    flatene2013 
WHERE   Apto='5Cest1' 
UNION
SELECT  cable  , Apto
FROM    flatene2013 
WHERE   Apto='5Cest2'
```

or if you dont mind about the `Apto`

```
SELECT  cable , Apto
FROM    flatene2013 
WHERE   Apto IN ('5C' , '5Cest1', '5Cest2')
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN Apto = '5C' THEN  Cable ELSE NULL END) as `5c`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Apto = '5Cest1' THEN  Cable ELSE NULL END) as `5Cest1`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Apto = '5Cest2' THEN  Cable ELSE NULL END) as `5Cest2`
FROM
        (
            SELECT  cable , Apto
            FROM    flatene2013 
            WHERE   Apto IN ('5C' , '5Cest1', '5Cest2')
        ) s
```

Comment: @JW great, it works, but I am having issues with placing the values in a <table> as in my example shown above. I need to have the three values placed in three different columns of my table

Comment: @JW i get the following error: An error occurred at line: 474 in the jsp file: /2013/enero/avisocobro5C.jsp
String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote

472:          Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
473:          String query;
474:          query="SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN Apto = '5C' THEN  Cable ELSE NULL END) as `5c`
475:           MAX(CASE WHEN Apto = '5Cest1' THEN  Cable ELSE NULL END) as `5Cest1`
476:              MAX(CASE WHEN Apto = '5Cest2' THEN  Cable ELSE NULL END) as `5Cest2`
477:     FROM

Comment: @JW any ideas? I am going crazy with this!

Comment: @Sheeyla do you have a comma after each case?

Answer (score 1):

Try using WHERE IN:

```
SELECT cable FROM flatene2013 WHERE Apto IN ('5C','5Cest1','5Cest2')
```

Comment: great, it works, but I am having issues with placing the values in a <table> as in my example shown above. I need to have the three values placed in three different columns of my table.

Comment: It is only retrieving the value for Apto 5C. I am using resultSet.getBigDecimal(1) as it is only one value that I need for each Apto, right? ... I am only getting the value for 5C three times.

Comment: and I get this error: java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set